# UITextField int data type xcode

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

I am trying to get a mathmetical equation to recognise a + /- sign of an integer (either -1 or +1) entered in a UItextfield (s1, s2). So if the user enters different signs the equations will be subtracted from each other.
It seems that the sign is not being recognised for some reason and the program just adds d1 and d2.

```
-(IBAction)calculateD:(id)sender{
float n1, r1, n2, r1, d, d1, d2;
int s1, s2;

s1= [textfieldS1.text intvalue]; //etc for all variables

d1 = s1 * ((n1-1)/r1);
d2 = s2 * ((n2-1)/r2);

if (s1 != s2) { d = d1 - d2;} 
else { d = d1 + d2;
}}
```

Any problems apparent in this code please?

Comment: In this code s1 and s2 are always going to be 0. You have not transferred the values from the textfields to your equations.

Comment: Thanks drekka just to clarify the variables have been initialised and the value pulled from the textfields I have edited the code to indicate this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to do here. Variables are not initialized and there is no specific reference to actual UITextField inside of the -calculateD: method. With this said, here are some hints, hope it will come in hand.

The signs s1, s2 are actually taken twice into a consideration. Once to produce d1, d2, and later to decide the (s1 != s2). Because of this, the latter will make sure you add two numbers of the same sign, possibly negating what you really want to obtain here. Example:

- say that s1=+1, s1=+1, then you got d = ((n1-1)/r1) + ((n2-1)/r2);
- say that s1=+1, s1=-1, then you got d = ((n1-1)/r1) + ((n2-1)/r2); the same as before;

Just drop the if, and leave a single: d = d1 + d2.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz I want the program to recognise the users input to add or subtract the 2 equations, the variables have been inititalised and the values of the variables obtained from  the textfields I have added this to the question

Comment: I have updated my answer with a simple example. Have a look, and tell us, if that is how you want the method to work.